# Pedometer simple app "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, pedometer

Noob IOS Dev can't figure out the error please, please some help
thread1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1,subcode=0x1003591fc)
Ive tried everything I could and nothing (well everything I understood from other codes)

```
var pedometer :CMPedometer!
var stepCount :Int = 0
@IBOutlet var labelSteps: UILabel!
@IBAction func btnStart(_ sender: Any) {
    *Pedometer*
    if CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() {
        self.pedometer.startUpdates(from: NSDate() as Date, withHandler: {
            data, error in
            if data != nil {
                // Add to existing counts
                self.stepCount += (data?.numberOfSteps as! Int)
                self.labelSteps.text = "\(self.stepCount)"

            }
        })
    }
}

@IBAction func btnStop(_ sender: Any) {
    //self.labelSteps.text = "0"
    //self.pedometer.stopUpdates()
    print("Stop")
}
```

Thanks. Hoping for a response soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pedometer may not have been initialised? Try:
`var pedometer = CMPedometer()`

Perhaps you haven't hooked up your `labelSteps` `IBOutlet` to the label in your storyboard/nib.

Could be one of those issues or both

Comment: Thank you. var pedometer = CMPedometer() was the solution to my problem.